# socket.io with phonegap build on android does not work

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, socket.io, phonegap

I've have an html5/javascript app that uses socket.io and it works just fine on the browser but when compile in Phonegap Build for Android socket.io does not connect when executing `socket = io.connect([server]:[port])`.

I've already tried a lot of possible solutions, none of them worked out. This is what I've tried already:

- using IP instead of full domain when connecting to socket.io
- socket.io connection done after `ondeviceready` event is triggered
- plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist` in config.xml
- plugin `https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket` in config.xml
- tried to use `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` in config.xml but Phonegap Build just does not go through with the compilation process and throws an error
- `access origin="*"` in config.xml
- `io.set('origins', ':')` in server code
- different socket.io transports (websockets, polling, etc)

I am using Phonegap's latest version 6.5.0 (Phonegap Build does not allow me to use a previous version like 6.4.5).

Whatever I do `socket.on("connect", function() { alert(socket.id) })` is never triggered on Android. On web, however, it alerts with the proper socket.id.

Also, I tried to check out log with `DEBUG=* node server.js` and nothing appears when using Android version.

Comment: How do you load socket.io.js in the phonegap app?

Comment: @mk12ok I have this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>` at the bottom of the index.html page.

Comment: It was finally solved by setting the socket.io script within <script></scrip> from the same domain as where it connects.

Comment: You can also bundle socket.io.js into the app. It will load quickly.

Comment: @mk12ok how would you bundle it into the app?

Comment: download it to `yourapp/www/js` folder and call it from the `index.html`